# How to disable the input field type = number from typing the values from keyboard?

Tags: javascript, input, user-input, onkeydown, onkeypress

I have the following **input** field. I want to disable the typing option but still want to keep the increment/decrement option of **number** field by clicking.

I used **min and max** but it doesn't help when I enter even a bigger value (like **9999**) by key press. It just allows any number by **keypress**.

How do I resolve it??

```js
  <input 
       type="number"
       id="inputCart"
      min="1"
      max="20"
      onChange={(e) => this.onChangeQty(e)}

      />
```

EDIT:

```js
<input className="text-center"
       type="number"
      min="1"
      class="numberInput"
      onChange={(e) => this.onChangeQty(e)}

      />
      
      
onChangeQty(e)
{
  const element = document.getElementsByClassName('numberInput');

function handleKeypress(e) {
  element[0].value = '';
    }

element[0].addEventListener('keyup', handleKeypress);
}
```

It still doesn't work and allow me to insert any value by key press

Comment: making your own disabled input and  adding two buttons for + / -

Answer (score 0):

```
 <input 
       type="number"
       id="inputCart"
      min="1"
      max="20"
      onChange={(e) => this.onChangeQty(e)}
      onKeyUp={e => e.preventDefault()}
      />
```

Set `onKeyUp`, pass the event and prevent the default action

Answer (score 0):

what you can do is get the reference (`getElementsByClassName`) of the input that you want to block, and add `addEventListener` to the `keyUp` event, that way, every time the user enters a value, you'll reset the value of the input and they can't type any number inside (The only way they can add a value is with the increment/decrement arrows). Eg:

```js
const element = document.getElementsByClassName('numberInput');

function handleKeypress(e) {
  element[0].value = '';
}

element[0].addEventListener('keyup', handleKeypress);
```

```html
<label for="numberInput">Number Input: </label>
<input type="number" name="quantity" min="1" max="100" class="numberInput">
```

Comment: Thanks. But How can I use getElementsByClassName in REACT JS?

Comment: Yeah, sure, `getElementsByClassName` is a native Js function, so you could use it in any Js framework out there with no problem. Only add the `event listener` when your component mount (Or in the life cycle you need it) and create a function to handle it every time it happens.

Comment: it still doesn't work and let me insert any value by key press.  please see my edit

Comment: @YellowMinion You can check this [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-mdcldd?embed=1&file=index.js) to see an implementation in React of what I'm talking about. PS: You don't really need the `onChange` eventHandler because you're using already and `event listener` and the `onChange` will block both keyboard input and Arrow keys inputs.

Comment: Thanks but Im handling it same way but its still allow me to insert any number

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code.

```js
function SupressInput($event) {
    $event.preventDefault();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>    
    <input max="10" min="1" onkeypress="SupressInput(event);" type="number">
</body>
```